# Canvas createPattern function not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a simple function designed to make it easier to create patterns using the canvas tag in HTML. I have an image on the site embedded with this code:

```html
    <style type="text/css">
        .invisible {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <img class="invisible" id="image" src="Images/test.png"></img>
```

and my function that makes a pattern is this:

```js
    //Function that allows you to create a pattern
    this.pattern = function(image, mode) {
        var pat = this.ctx.createPattern(image, mode);
        return pat;
    };
```

but when I try to call the function with this code:

```js
var testImage = document.getElementById("image");
myCanvas.fill(myCanvas.pattern(testImage, "repeat"));
```

an error appears in the log that says this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
```

now, I'm pretty sure the variable that I put in was an HTMLImageElement, but the error is still there.

full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Canvas Library</title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .invisible {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
     <body>
        <p id="text">Unknown</p>
        <canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Canvas.js"></script>
        <img class="invisible" id="image" src="Images/test.png"></img>
        </body>

</html>
```

```js
// JavaScript File
var Canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var label = document.getElementById("text");
var testImage = document.getElementById("image");

var distance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var a = Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2);
    var b = Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2);
    return Math.sqrt(a + b);
};

//Declare the Canvas Object
var canvas = function(src) {
    //Function to see if a line is colliding with a certain point Has an accuracy of about 1 pixel
    this.lineIsColliding = function(startX, startY, endX, endY, testX, testY) {
        const v1 = {
            x: endX - startX,
            y: endY - startY
        };
        const l2 = v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y;
        if (l2 === 0) {
            return false;
        } // line has no length so can't be near anything
        const v2 = {
            x: testX - startX,
            y: testY - startY
        };
        const u = (v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y) / l2;
        return u >= 0 && u <= 1 && Math.abs((v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x) / Math.sqrt(l2)) < 1;
    };

    //The Canvas to draw on
    this.src = src;
    //The context of source(used for drawing)
    this.ctx = this.src.getContext("2d");
    //The Mouse Move Function
    this.showCoordinates = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        label.innerHTML = "<b>x: </b>" + e.offsetX + " <b>y: </b>" + e.offsetY + ", " + myCanvas.lineIsColliding(358, 277, 365, 268, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    };
    //Show coordinates variable
    this.showCoordinatesBool = true;
    //The boolean to tell if we should use stroke
    var useStroke = true;
    //The fill style and stroke style(can be color, pattern, or gradient)
    this.fillStyle = "#000000";
    this.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    //The Line cap style (can be butt, square, or round)
    this.lineCap = "butt";
    //The Stroke Weight (how wide the strokes are)
    this.strokeWeightVar = "default";
    //The corner style (how the corners are drawn)
    this.cornerStyle = "miter";
    //The Shadow Color
    this.shadowColorVar = "#000000";
    //The shadow Blur
    this.shadowBlurVar = 0;
    //The shadow Offsets
    this.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    this.shadowOffsetY = 0;

    //Function to set the fill style
    this.fill = function(style) {
        this.fillStyle = style;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = style;
    };

    //Function to set the stroke style
    this.stroke = function(style) {
        this.useStroke = true;
        this.strokeStyle = style;
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = style;
    };

    //Function to delete the stroke
    this.noStroke = function() {
        this.useStroke = false;
    };

    //Function to draw a rectangle
    this.rect = function(x, y, width, height) {
        this.ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        if (this.useStroke) {
            this.ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
        }

    };

    //Function to draw a corner
    this.corner = function(style, centerX, centerY, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        this.ctx.lineJoin = style;
        this.cornerStyle = style;
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
        this.ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
        this.ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
        this.ctx.stroke();
    };

    //Function to draw a hollow rectangle
    this.hollowRect = function(x, y, width, height) {
        this.ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
    };

    //Function to set the canvas background 
    this.background = function(style) {
        this.fillStyle = style;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = style;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.src.width, this.src.height);
    };

    //Function to draw a line
    this.line = function(startX, startY, endX, endY) {
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
        this.ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
        this.ctx.stroke();
    };

    //Function to change line style
    this.lineCap = function(mode) {
        this.ctx.lineCap = mode;
        this.lineCap = mode;
    };

    //Function to change stroke weight
    this.strokeWeight = function(weight) {
        this.useStroke = true;
        this.ctx.lineWidth = weight;
        this.strokeWeightVar = weight;
    };

    //Function to clear a certain area
    this.clearArea = function(x, y, width, height) {
        this.ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
    };
    //Turn the show coordinate function on
    this.enableCoordinates = function() {
        this.showCoordinatesBool = true;
        this.src.addEventListener("mousemove", this.showCoordinates);
    };
    /*Shadows*/

    //Set the shadow color
    this.shadowColor = function(color) {
        this.shadowColorVar = color;
        this.ctx.shadowColor = color;
    };
    //Set the shadow blur
    this.shadowBlur = function(blur) {
        this.shadowBlurVar = blur;
        this.ctx.shadowBlur = blur;
    };
    //Set the shadow offset
    this.shadowOffset = function(offsetX, offsetY) {
        this.shadowOffsetX = offsetX;
        this.shadowOffsetY = offsetY;
        this.ctx.shadowOffsetX = offsetX;
        this.ctx.shadowOffsetY = offsetY;
    };
    //Remove shadows
    this.noShadow = function() {
        this.shadowOffset(0, 0);
        this.shadowColor("#000000");
        this.shadowBlur(0);
    };

    //Function to see if a rectangle is colliding with a specific point
    this.rectIsColliding = function(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight, testX, testY) {
        this.ctx.rect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
        return this.ctx.isPointInPath(testX, testY);
    };
    //Function that returns a custom linear gradient
    this.linearGradient = function(startX, startY, endX, endY, colorStops) {
        var gradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(startX, startY, endX, endY);
        for (var i = 0; i < colorStops.length; i++) {
            gradient.addColorStop(colorStops[i].location, colorStops[i].color);
        }
        return gradient;
    };
    //Function that returns a custom radial gradient
    this.radialGradient = function(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1, colorStops) {
        var radialGradientVar = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1);
        for (var i = 0; i < colorStops.length; i++) {
            radialGradientVar.addColorStop(colorStops[i].location, colorStops[i].color);
        }
        return radialGradientVar;
    };
    //Function that allows you to create a pattern
    this.pattern = function(image, mode) {
        var pat = this.ctx.createPattern(image, mode);
        return pat;
    };
};

//The following code is for testing purposes ONLY!
{
    //Create a new canvas
    var myCanvas = new canvas(Canvas);
    //Set the Background Color
    myCanvas.background("#ff0000");
    //Set the fill color
    myCanvas.fill("#0000ff");
    //Set the Stroke Color
    myCanvas.stroke("#00ff00");
    //Draw a rectangle
    myCanvas.rect(164, 153, 50, 100);
    //Draw a hollow rectangle
    myCanvas.hollowRect(300, 300, 50, 50);
    //Disable the Stroke
    myCanvas.noStroke();
    //Draw a rectangle with no stroke
    myCanvas.rect(21, 18, 50, 50);
    //Change the Stroke color
    myCanvas.stroke("#ffff00");
    //Change the stroke weight
    myCanvas.strokeWeight(10);
    //Change the line cap
    myCanvas.lineCap("round");
    //Draw a line
    myCanvas.line(350, 30, 250, 80);
    //Draw a corner
    myCanvas.corner("miter", 50, 135, 100, 185, 100, 110);
    //Enable the Coordinates
    myCanvas.enableCoordinates();
    //Clear a space from the canvas
    myCanvas.clearArea(6, 245, 100, 100);
    //Set the Shadow Color
    myCanvas.shadowColor("black");
    //Set the shadow Blur
    myCanvas.shadowBlur(20);
    //Set the shadow offset
    myCanvas.shadowOffset(10, 0);
    //Set the stroke
    myCanvas.noStroke();
    //Set the fill color
    myCanvas.fill("orange");
    //Draw a rectangle
    myCanvas.rect(268, 167, 30, 30);
    //Remove the shadow
    myCanvas.noShadow();
    //Test if the rectangle is colliding with a specific point
    if (myCanvas.rectIsColliding(268, 167, 30, 30, 290, 170)) {
        myCanvas.fill("green");
        myCanvas.rect(358, 0, 50, 46);
    }
    else {
        myCanvas.fill("yellow");
        myCanvas.rect(362, 0, 50, 46);
    }

    //Test if a line is colliding with a certain point
    console.log("function returned: " + myCanvas.lineIsColliding(358, 277, 365, 268, 362, 271));
    if (myCanvas.lineIsColliding(358, 277, 365, 268, 362, 271)) {
        console.log("line is colliding!");
        myCanvas.line(358, 277, 365, 268);
    }
    else {
        console.log("line is not colliding!");

    }

    myCanvas.line(0, 0, 50, 10);

    //Color stop used for creating gradients
    var colorStop = function(location, color) {
        this.location = location;
        this.color = color;
    };

    console.log(distance(0, 0, 50, 10));

    myCanvas.fill(myCanvas.linearGradient(259, 77, 359, 127, [new colorStop(0.0, "green"), new colorStop(1.0, "blue")]));
    myCanvas.rect(259, 87, 100, 50);
    myCanvas.fill(myCanvas.radialGradient(309, 225, 10, 309, 225, 50, [new colorStop(0.0, "yellow"), new colorStop(1.0, "green")]));
    myCanvas.rect(259, 200, 100, 50);
    myCanvas.fill(myCanvas.pattern(testImage, "repeat"));
    myCanvas.rect(132, 81, 50, 100);
}
```

Comment: At the time your script is executed `<img id="image">` is not parsed and thus not in the DOM yet. Hence document.getElementBy('image') will return null.Either execute your script only when the page has loaded (best), either insert it at the bottom of your html markup (but then you will have to wait for the load event of your image to be able to vreate a pattern from it).

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your code after your image is loaded.

```
testImage.addEventListener('load', start)
```

But better way to is to create image from javascript, so you can sure that image `onload` has't yet emitted.

```
var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener('load', start);
image.addEventListener('error', errorfn);

image.src = 'Images/test.png'
```

There is working [Sample](http://jsbin.com/mipirehidu/edit?js,output). I don't see rendered pattern image, but either no errors in console and that image definitely loads.

Comment: I inserted this code:                                                                      
    //Function that allows you to create a pattern
    this.pattern = function(image, mode) {
        image.onload = function() {
            var pat = this.ctx.createPattern(image, mode);
            return pat;
        };
    };, and another error came up that said: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null
    at canvas.pattern (Canvas.js:191)
    at Canvas.js:279 Sorry, but I don't know how to format comments.

Comment: I used this other solution (code here: https://jsfiddle.net/vqrywvv2/), but the log says, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at canvas.pattern (Canvas.js:195)
    at Canvas.js:281"

Comment: When I type this code, the computer says that "Image is not defined."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150887/discussion-between-ptolemy2002-and-firanolfind).